# Use NVIDIA card on debian testing

Tags: debian, nvidia

Every time I start cinnamon I see "cinnamon is currently running without hardware acceleration, and as a result, you may observe much higher than normal CPU usage" and it seems my nvidia card isn't doing any work. Here's my install process

uname -a

```
Linux myhostname 5.7.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.7.6-1 (2020-06-24) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

/etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ testing main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ testing main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security testing-security main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security testing-security main contrib non-free
```

```
$ nvidia-detect
Detected NVIDIA GPUs:
01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] [10de:139b] (rev a2)

Checking card:  NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] (rev a2)
Your card is supported by all driver versions.
Your card is also supported by the Tesla 440 drivers series.
Your card is also supported by the Tesla 418 drivers series.
It is recommended to install the
    nvidia-driver
package.
```

so I `sudo apt install nvidia-driver` which is a pretty uneventful install except for the one message I have to confirm:

```
Conflicting nouveau kernel module loaded

The free nouveau kernel module is currently loaded and conflicts with the non-free nvidia kernel module.

The easiest way to fix this is to reboot the machine once the installation has finished.
```

After install I have nouveau blacklisted:

```
$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-blacklists-nouveau.conf 
# You need to run "update-initramfs -u" after editing this file.

# see #580894
blacklist nouveau
```

After a reboot, there's some stuff from `lsmod`

```
$ lsmod | grep -i nvidia
nvidia_drm             53248  0
nvidia_modeset       1118208  1 nvidia_drm
nvidia              20717568  22 nvidia_modeset
ipmi_msghandler        73728  2 ipmi_devintf,nvidia
drm_kms_helper        249856  2 nvidia_drm,i915
drm                   606208  6 drm_kms_helper,nvidia_drm,i915
```

from `lspci` I get

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

and for the nvidia card

```
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Dell XPS 15 9550
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 143, IOMMU group 1
    Memory at dc000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at dd000000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidia
```

```
$ nvidia-settings --verbose

WARNING: NV-CONTROL extension not found on this Display.


ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system
```

Searching around I see a lot of references to using an ubuntu command `prime-select`. Any debian suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the nouveau driver is loaded instead of the non-free nvidia driver. [In the wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers#Troubleshooting) it is suggested that you configure Xorg for the nvidia driver, blacklist nouveau and then reboot.

You should first check if Xorg is already configured (look in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-nvidia.conf` or similar), and if it isn't configured install the `nvidia-xconfig` package and run it with sudo to automatically generate. (As suggested [here](https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers#configure))

Afterwards, blacklist nouveau by running:

```
sudo echo "blacklist nouveau" > /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf 
sudo echo "options nouveau modeset=0" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf
```

And then reboot.

Comment: I had a nouveau blacklist already, and updated the question to reflect that. nvidia-xconfig seems to be only relevant for old debian versions, and trying to use it left me in a broken state where X didn't seem to start at all and I couldn't even switch to a virtual terminal to login.